# Hardware-accelerated JPEG Compression on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I have a stereo camera connected to a Raspberry Pi. I want to get images off it, compress them, and send them to a PC continuously. I am trying to use MMAL for this.

I have this code to test it out:

```py
from picamera import mmal, mmalobj
import cv2
import io
from threading import Event

finished = Event()  # triggered whenever it finishes compressing an image

image = cv2.imread('image.png')
image = cv2.resize(image, (3200, 1300))
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

encoder = mmalobj.MMALImageEncoder()

encoder.inputs[0].format = mmal.MMAL_ENCODING_I420
encoder.inputs[0].framesize = (3200, 1300)
encoder.inputs[0].commit()

encoder.outputs[0].copy_from(encoder.inputs[0])
encoder.outputs[0].format = mmal.MMAL_ENCODING_JPEG
encoder.outputs[0].commit()
encoder.outputs[0].params[mmal.MMAL_PARAMETER_JPEG_Q_FACTOR] = 90


def image_callback(port, buf):
    jpg_data.write(buf.data)

    if bool(buf.flags & mmal.MMAL_BUFFER_HEADER_FLAG_FRAME_END):
        finished.set()
        return True

    return False


# perform compression on the image 100 times
for i in range(100):
    finished.clear()

    encoder.inputs[0].enable(lambda port, buf: True)
    encoder.outputs[0].enable(image_callback)

    jpg_data = io.BytesIO()
    buf = encoder.inputs[0].get_buffer()
    buf.data = image[:]
    encoder.inputs[0].send_buffer(buf)

    finished.wait()

    jpg_data.close()
    encoder.inputs[0].disable()
    encoder.outputs[0].disable()
```

This only works if I disable and reenable the ports on every iteration. However, it is slower than just using OpenCV:

```py
import cv2
import io

image = cv2.imread('image.png')
image = cv2.resize(image, (3200, 1300))
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# perform compression on the image 100 times
for i in range(100):
    success, buffer = cv2.imencode(".jpg", image)
    io_buffer = io.BytesIO(buffer)
    data = io_buffer.read()
```

Also, I found that the disabling and reenabling was taking up about half the time. Does anyone know why this is happening, and if there is a faster way? Thanks.

Comment: Still looking at this but your OpenCV code can actually go 3-4x faster if you remove the last two lines and replace them with `data = buffer.tobytes()`

Comment: Also, I am not sure that the JPEG Q factor is directly comparable between **MMAL** and **OpenCV**. If I run the same image through your MMAL code I get a compressed JPEG of 2.4MB but with OpenCV I get 700kB so over 3x the size difference. I know the JPEG Q factor is vastly different on `raspistill` versus **ImageMagick** see https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=73174

Comment: `buffer.tobytes()` didn't speed it up for me. I think you're write about the Q factor though.  I changed it to 22 for MMAL and now the file sizes are similar.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to include `(image>>2).astype('uint8')` in the second example. I've edited it.